# Sort numbers into three groups s.t. their sums are close to a certain value

Tags: algorithms

I have a list of numbers (let's call it `L`) and I need to split this list into three groups (`A`, `B`, and `C`) such that the sum of the numbers in each group (`sum(A)`, `sum(B)`, `sum(C)`) is as close as possible to the `sum(L) / 3`.

I'm sure it is an old problem, but I couldn't find a solution. The closest I got is to sort `L`, then put every third number starting from the first element into `A`, then put every third number starting from the second element into `B`, and put the rest into `C`. But it doesn't always work, especially if numbers in `L` are not uniformly distributed.

Comment: This sounds like a 3-way variation of the [Partition Problem](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), more specifically, its optimization variant.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Indeed, it is the optimization of the partition problem with 3 subsets. I guess I will go with the greedy algorithm from the Wikipedia article, which is a little more clever than my initial approach, but essentially uses the same strategy. Thank you.